# Why my json data not following an order in API 16 and lower API?

Tags: android, json

Explanation:I have json.In which, i have object namely matches.Inside the matches object i have lot of objects.I mean data->season->matches->object1,2,3 so on.
This objects are dynamic it's not fixed at the run-time.I tried to parse the matches object.

Here is my json data

[image]

Now i tried to parse this file using my url.I was used a volley network library to parse the json file from server.

Here is my code to parse the json and get the response

```
public class SeriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    String series_key = "";
    String url = "";
    String access_token = "";
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    List<SeriesMatches> series_header;
    HashMap<SeriesMatches, List<SeriesMatches>> series_child;

    String winner_team = "";
    String overs = "";
    String wickets_now = "";
    String now_runs = "";
    String now_bat_team = "";
    String fullScore = "";
    String team_name = "";
    String[] over_parts;


    ExpandableListView expListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_series);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.adbar);
        new AddLoader(getApplicationContext()).LoadAds(frameLayout);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SaveTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
        access_token = sharedPreferences.getString("accessToken", null);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        series_key = intent.getStringExtra("series_key");
        url = "https://api.litzscore.com/rest/v2/season/" + series_key + "/?access_token=" + access_token + "&card_type=summary_card";
        if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
            dialog_popup();
        } else {
            getSeriesMatches();
        }
    }

    public void getSeriesMatches() {
        String str_req = "getSeries";

        StringRequest matches_req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (!object.getBoolean("status") || object.getString("status_code").equals("403")) {
//                            DialogAbandoned abandoned=new DialogAbandoned(getApplicationContext());
//                            abandoned.setDialog("Series","Data Coming soon...");
                        } else {
                            series_header = new ArrayList<>();
                            series_child = new HashMap<>();
                            if (object.has("data") && !object.isNull("data")) {
                                JSONObject data = object.getJSONObject("data");
                                JSONObject season;
                                JSONObject matches;
                                if (data.has("season") && !data.isNull("season")) {
                                    season = data.getJSONObject("season");
                                    if (season.has("matches") && !season.isNull("matches")) {
                                        matches = season.getJSONObject("matches");
                                        JSONArray matches_arr = matches.names();
                                        JSONObject matches_obj;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < matches_arr.length(); i++) {
                                            SeriesMatches s_matches = new SeriesMatches();
                                            matches_obj = matches.getJSONObject(matches_arr.getString(i));

                                            JSONObject teams = matches_obj.getJSONObject("teams");
                                            JSONObject team_a = teams.getJSONObject("a");
                                            JSONObject team_b = teams.getJSONObject("b");


                                            JSONObject start_date = matches_obj.getJSONObject("start_date");
                                            s_matches.setRealted_name(matches_obj.getString("related_name"));
                                            series_header.add(s_matches);

                                            if (!matches_obj.isNull("msgs") && matches_obj.has("msgs")) {
                                                JSONObject msgs = matches_obj.getJSONObject("msgs");
                                                winner_team = "";
                                                if (msgs.has("info")) {
                                                    winner_team = msgs.getString("info");
                                                }
                                            }

                                            JSONObject now;
                                            now_bat_team = "";
                                            now_runs = "";
                                            wickets_now = "";
                                            overs = "";
                                            if (matches_obj.has("now") && !matches_obj.isNull("now")) {
                                                now = matches_obj.getJSONObject("now");
                                                if (now.has("batting_team")) {
                                                    now_bat_team = now.getString("batting_team");
                                                }
                                                if (now.has("runs")) {
                                                    if (now.getString("runs").equals("0")) {
                                                        now_runs = "0";
                                                    } else {
                                                        now_runs = now.getString("runs");
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                if (now.has("runs_str") && !now.isNull("runs_str")) {
                                                    if (now.getString("runs_str").equals("0")) {
                                                        overs = "0";
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (now.getString("runs_str").equals("null")) {
                                                            overs = "0";
                                                        } else {
                                                            over_parts = now.getString("runs_str").split(" ");
                                                            overs = over_parts[2];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (now.has("wicket")) {
                                                    if (now.getString("wicket").equals("0")) {
                                                        wickets_now = "0";
                                                    } else {
                                                        wickets_now = now.getString("wicket");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            JSONArray team_arr = teams.names();
                                            JSONObject team_obj;
                                            for (int a = 0; a < team_arr.length(); a++) {
                                                if (now_bat_team.equals(team_arr.getString(a))) {
                                                    team_obj = teams.getJSONObject(team_arr.getString(a));
                                                    team_name = "";
                                                    if (team_obj.has("short_name") && !team_obj.isNull("short_name")) {
                                                        team_name = team_obj.getString("short_name");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (matches_obj.has("status_overview") && !matches_obj.isNull("status_overview")) {
                                                if (matches_obj.getString("status_overview").equals("abandoned") || matches_obj.getString("status_overview").equals("canceled")) {
                                                    fullScore = "";
                                                } else {
                                                    fullScore = team_name + " - " + now_runs + "/" + wickets_now + " (" + overs + " ovr)";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            SeriesMatches s2 = new SeriesMatches();
                                            s2.setTeam_Aname(team_a.getString("short_name"));
                                            s2.setTemm_Akey(team_a.getString("key"));
                                            s2.setTeam_Bname(team_b.getString("short_name"));
                                            s2.setTeam_Bkey(team_b.getString("key"));
                                            s2.setStatus(matches_obj.getString("status"));
                                            s2.setDate(start_date.getString("iso"));
                                            s2.setVenue(matches_obj.getString("venue"));
                                            s2.setMsgs(winner_team);
                                            s2.setScore(fullScore);
                                            s2.setMom(matches_obj.getString("man_of_match"));
                                            List<SeriesMatches> matches_info = new ArrayList<>();
                                            matches_info.add(s2);
                                            series_child.put(series_header.get(i), matches_info);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                ExpandedListAdapter adapter = new ExpandedListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), series_header, series_child);
                expListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    dialog_popup();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    dialog_popup();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    dialog_popup();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    dialog_popup();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    dialog_popup();
                }
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(matches_req, str_req);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Expnadedlistview

```
public class ExpandedListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<SeriesMatches> series_header;
    private HashMap<SeriesMatches,List<SeriesMatches>> series_child;
    private Typeface tf;

    public ExpandedListAdapter(Context context,List<SeriesMatches> series_header,HashMap<SeriesMatches,List<SeriesMatches>> series_child){
        this.context=context;
        this.series_header=series_header;
        this.series_child=series_child;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.series_header.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.series_child.get(this.series_header.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.series_header.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.series_child.get(this.series_header.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
        }
        TextView text_group=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        SeriesMatches s=series_header.get(groupPosition);
        text_group.setText(s.getRealted_name());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child,null);
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getResources().getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        }
        TextView teamA=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_one_country_name);
        TextView teamB=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_two_country_name);
        TextView txt_venue=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.venue);
        TextView txtTimeIST=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_timeist);
        TextView txtTimeGMT=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_timegmt);
        TextView txtDate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);

        ImageView team_one_flag_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_one_flag_icon);
        ImageView team_two_flag_icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.team_two_flag_icon);
        SeriesMatches s1=series_child.get(series_header.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

        String team_a_key=s1.getTemm_Akey();
        String team_b_key=s1.getTeam_Bkey();

        teamA.setText(s1.getTeam_Aname());
        teamB.setText(s1.getTeam_Bname());

        if(team_a_key.equals("ind")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ind);

        }
        else if(team_a_key.equals("omn")){
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.omn);
        }
        else if(team_a_key.equals("afg")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.afg);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("aus")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.aus);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("ban")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ban);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("eng")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.eng);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("hkg")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hkg);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("ire")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ire);
        } else if(team_a_key.equals("nl")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nl);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("nz")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nz);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("pak")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pak);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("rsa")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsa);

        }else if (team_a_key.equalsIgnoreCase("sl")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sl);

        } else if (team_a_key.equals("uae")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.uae);

        } else if (team_a_key.equals("wi")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wi);

        } else if (team_a_key.equals("zim")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.zim);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("sct")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sct);

            //////////   IPL  Team ///////////

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("dd")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dd);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("kkr")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.kkr);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("mi")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mi);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("srh")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sh);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("kxip")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.kxip);
        } else if(team_a_key.equals("rcb")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rcb);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("rps")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps);

        } else if(team_a_key.equals("gl")) {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.gl);

        } else {
            team_one_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dft);
        }

        //for B TEAM
        if(team_b_key.equals("ind")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ind);

        }
        else if(team_b_key.equals("omn")){
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.omn);
        }
        else if(team_b_key.equals("afg")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.afg);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("aus")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.aus);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("ban")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ban);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("eng")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.eng);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("hkg")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hkg);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("ire")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ire);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("nl")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nl);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("nz")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nz);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("pak")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pak);

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("rsa")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rsa);
        }else if (team_b_key.equalsIgnoreCase("sl")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sl);
        } else if (team_b_key.equals("uae")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.uae);

        } else if (team_b_key.equals("wi")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wi);
        } else if (team_b_key.equals("zim")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.zim);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("sct")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sct);

            //////////   IPL   ///////////

        } else if(team_b_key.equals("dd")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dd);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("kkr")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.kkr);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("mi")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mi);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("srh")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sh);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("kxip")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.kxip);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("rcb")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rcb);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("rps")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps);
        } else if(team_b_key.equals("gl")) {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.gl);
        } else {
            team_two_flag_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dft);
        }

        try {
            String[] fullDate;

            String fullTime = "";

            DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'+00':ss");
            utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            String ist=outputFormat.format(utcFormat.parse(s1.getDate()));
            Date timestamp;
            timestamp = utcFormat.parse(s1.getDate());

            fullDate = timestamp.toString().split(" ");
            String monthName = fullDate[1];
            String Dayname = fullDate[2];
            fullTime = fullDate[3];

            String[] gmt_fulldate = s1.getDate().split("T");
            String gmt_time = gmt_fulldate[1];
            String[] gmt_hour_parts = gmt_time.split("\\+");

            String finalDate = Dayname + " " + monthName;
            String finalTimeIST = ist + " IST | " + gmt_hour_parts[0] + " GMT";

            String[] venue_parts=s1.getVenue().split(",");
            int length=venue_parts.length;
            if(length==1){
                txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                txtTimeGMT.setText(venue_parts[0]);
            }
            if(length==2){
                txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
                txtTimeGMT.setText(venue_parts[0] + "," + venue_parts[1]);

            }
            if(length==3){
                txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
                txtTimeGMT.setText(venue_parts[1] + "," + venue_parts[2]);
            }
            if(length==4){
                txtTimeGMT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
                txtTimeGMT.setText(venue_parts[2] + "," + venue_parts[3]);
            }
            if(s1.getStatus().equals("notstarted")){
                txtDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
                txtDate.setTypeface(tf);
                txtDate.setText("Started on " + finalDate);
                txtTimeIST.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtTimeIST.setText(finalTimeIST);

            }
            if(s1.getStatus().equals("completed")){
                txtDate.setTypeface(tf);
                txtDate.setText(s1.getScore());
                txtDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
                txtTimeIST.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtTimeIST.setText(s1.getMsgs());
                Log.e("NOTSTARTED","DONE");
                txt_venue.setText("MOM : "+s1.getMom().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s1.getMom().substring(1).replace("_", " "));
            }
        }
        catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Problem is i have mobile in which jellybean is installed.In the jellybean or lower of jellybean it's not comes in the order.If same code i ran into lollipop or marshmallow it's comes into the order.Order like

1. trieseries_2016_g1
2. trieseries_2016_g2

until trieseries_2016_final

Here is a screenshort of marshmallow

[image]
please, help me to solve out this problem.

Here is a sceenshort of jellybean

[image]

Comment: I didn't check your code.. But the best way will be using a " Comparator " to make the items in the order you want before passing to the adapter.

Comment: ohk but how to use coparator while i have different objects?

Comment: If you have is a list use this for getting a increasing order "sortedList =Collections.sort(list);"

Comment: ohk I will try to implement.